# Interval average of 1D data

Tags: python, numpy, average

I have two 1D arrays, one for measured data and the other one for location. For example, the measured data could be temperature and the other array the heights of the measurement:

```
temp = np.asarray([10, 9.6, 9.3, ..., -20.3, -21.0])  # Temperature in celsius
height = np.asarray([129, 145, 167, ..., 5043, 5112]) # Height in meters
```

As you can see, the height of the measurements is not regularly spaced.

I want to compute the mean temperature in regularly spaced height intervals. This is some kind of moving average, but the window size is variable, because the data points inside the interval of interest is not always the same.

This could be done with a for loop in the following way:

```
regular_heights = np.arange(0, 6000, 100) # Regular heights every 100m
regular_temps = []

for i in range(len(regular_heights)-1):
    mask = np.logical_and(height > regular_heights[i], height < regular_heights[i+1])
    mean = np.mean(temp[mask])
    regular_temps.append(mean)

regular_temps = np.hstack((regular_temps))
```

I don't like this approach that much and I was wondering if there would be a more "numpy-style" solution.

Comment: Do you want a "moving average" or "the mean temp in regularly spaced intervals"?  That is, if you have N intervals, to you want N averages, or do you want a continuous average using a moving window (that spans a range of heights at each location)?

Comment: As I say in my commnet to @elyase 's  answer, I probably need to di first a mean in regularly spaced intervals and then smooth it with a spline. However, a moving average could also be good in combination with a spline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for [UnivariateSpline](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline). For example:

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

temp = np.asarray([10, 9.6, 9.3, 9.0, 8.7])    # Temperature in celsius
height = np.asarray([129, 145, 167, 190, 213]) # Height in meters
f = UnivariateSpline(height, temp)
```

Now you can evaluate `f` wherever you want:

```
regular_heights = np.arange(120, 213, 5)       # Regular heights every 5m
plot(height, temp, 'o', regular_heights, f(regular_heights), 'x')
```

[image]

Comment: The `f(regular_heights)` gives interpolated value at those points. Not what OP asked -- the mean of values within height intervals.

Comment: I know he mentioned the 'mean' but in a rather vague way(mean of what?). It looks like this is what he actually wants, thats why I said 'probably looking for...'. If you want you can post an answer with the mean, I guess we will find out eventually what he is after.

Comment: `UnivariateSpline`looks fine for data taken in a vertical profile, however, in my case, the data is taken simultaneously at different locations the values are very different. Perhaps my solution needs a combination of both approaches, first an average to get a regularly spaced dataset and the apply a spline to get a smooth curve.

Comment: i don't know exactly how your data looks but you might want to check into this: http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/modules/gaussian_process.html